# Instrumental tests (Espresso) working locally but flaky on the Gitlab CI

Tags: android, continuous-integration, automated-tests, junit4, android-espresso

I have a set of instrumental tests, pretty simple espresso tests. When I launch them locally on an emulator every test passes. But on my CI they are super flaky, there are always 2 or 3 out of 9 that doesn't pass, and they are not always the same. I am wondering if it could be because of the server that is too slow, because now that it's night and no one else uses it my tests seem to always pass... It's pretty weird, is there any way to launch the test slowly to make sure to not have this problem, or maybe the problem comes from somewhere else..?

FYI my local emulator is on the same Android version as the CI (24), and my CI is running on Gitlab.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"
  EMULATOR_VERSION: "24"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./LoupAppProject/gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build
  - unit-test
  - instrumental-test

lintDebug:
  tags: ["android"]
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd LoupAppProject/
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :LoupApp:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

assembleDebug:
  tags: ["android"]
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd LoupAppProject/
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - cd LoupAppProject/
    - LoupAppProject/LoupApp/build/outputs/

debugTests:
  tags: ["android"]
  stage: unit-test
  script:
    - cd LoupAppProject/
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :LoupApp:testDebug

instrumentation_tests:
  tags: ["android"]
  stage: instrumental-test
  script:
    - apt-get --quiet update --yes
    - apt-get --quiet install --yes libx11-dev libpulse0 libgl1 libnss3 libxcomposite-dev libxcursor1 libasound2
    - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
    - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
    - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "emulator" "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};default;armeabi-v7a"  > installEmulator.log
    - echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};default;armeabi-v7a"
    - android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator
    # Turn off animations
    - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
    - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
    - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - cd ./LoupAppProject
    - ./gradlew connectedCheck
```

Example of test :

```
@Test
    public void d_addRecordToLoupWithName() throws InterruptedException {
        setupIdlingResource(new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(R.id.remaining_time, View.VISIBLE));
        onView(withId(R.id.content)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, scrollTo()));
        onView(withId(R.id.content)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));
        setupIdlingResource(new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(R.id.fab, View.VISIBLE));
        onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());
        setupIdlingResource(new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(R.id.button_microphone, View.VISIBLE));
        onView(withId(R.id.button_microphone)).perform(click());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        onView(withId(R.id.button_microphone)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.goto_next)).perform(click());
        setupIdlingResource(new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(R.id.et_recording_name, View.VISIBLE));
        onView(allOf(instanceOf(EditText.class), withId(R.id.et_recording_name))).perform(replaceText(RECORD_NAME));
        onView(withId(R.id.goto_next)).perform(click());
        setupIdlingResource(new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(R.id.recording_name, View.VISIBLE));
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recording_name))).check(matches(withText(is(RECORD_NAME))));
        onView(withId(R.id.goto_next)).perform(click());
        setupIdlingResource(new ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(R.id.uploading, View.VISIBLE));
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.uploading))).check(matches(withText(R.string.record_uploading_upload_hint)));
    }
```

Here is my class ViewVisibilityIdlinResource :

```
public class ViewVisibilityIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    @IdRes
    private final int viewId;
    private final int expectedVisibility;

    private boolean mIdle;
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    public ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(@IdRes final int viewId, final int expectedVisibility) {
        this.viewId = viewId;
        this.expectedVisibility = expectedVisibility;
        this.mIdle = false;
        this.resourceCallback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return ViewVisibilityIdlingResource.class.getSimpleName() + "_" + viewId;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isIdleNow() {
        if(getCurrentActivity() == null) {
            mIdle = false;
        } else {
            View view = getCurrentActivity().findViewById(viewId);
            mIdle = mIdle || view != null && view.getVisibility() == expectedVisibility;

            if (mIdle) {
                if (resourceCallback != null) {
                    resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
                }
            }
        }
        return mIdle;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

}
```

Comment: This guy had the same issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPlHmKjQUWo